# Retrieving which users have made check-in in a place

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get who made a check-in from a place via Graph API or another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) through this url

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/checkins?access_token=...
```

And you cal also use FQL to retrive information from checkin table. [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/checkin/) is the link

Comment: the right way to do this via graph API its

https://graph.facebook.com/LOCAL_ID/checkins




thanks.

Comment: @FernandoSousa its good that if you got solution. I provided the link of FQL so that you can get all information of checkins.